# How to create taxonomy values for pages and list them in wp-admin

Tags: categories, pages

With WordPress version 4.9.4,
I'm looking for way to create taxonomy data for pages.  If this is possible, I would like to understand (1) how this works, and (2) how to list that taxonomy value under a new column on the `/edit.php?post_type=page` in wp-admin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely possible, and pretty easy too!

If you'd like to register an existing taxonomy (i.e. `category`) with an existing post type (i.e `page`), [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) can be used. E.g.:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_register_category_tax_for_page' );
function wpse_register_category_tax_for_page() {
    $taxonomy    = 'category';
    $object_type = 'page';

    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( $taxonomy, $object_type );
}
```

A new taxonomy can be created and associated with an new/existing post type as well. In this example, the taxonomy `classification` is associated with the existing post type, `page`:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_register_custom_taxonomy', 0 );
function wpse_register_custom_taxonomy() {
    // Arguments for register_taxonomy().
    $args = [
        'public'            => true,
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'label'             => __( 'Classification', 'textdomain' ),
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => 'classification',
        'rewrite'           => [ 'slug' => 'classification' ],
    ];

    // Array of post types to associate with this taxonomy.
    $post_types = [ 'page' ];

    register_taxonomy( 'classification', $post_types, $args );
}
```

Note that the parameter `$show_admin_column` has been set to `true` here. This will ensure that the taxonomy column will be added to the `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page` screen.

Let's pretend that some other plugin registered the `classification` taxonomy and set the `$show_admin_column` parameter to `false`. We can use the `register_taxonomy_args` to override the original setting and ensure that the taxonomy appears in the admin columns:

```
add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', 'wpse_edit_taxonomy_args', 10, 3 );
function wpse_edit_taxonomy_args( $args, $taxonomy, $object_type ) {
    // Array of taxonomies to change arguments on.
    $taxonomies = [
        'classification',
    ];

    // Set $show_admin_column to true.
    if ( in_array( $taxonomy, $taxonomies ) ) {
        $args[ 'show_admin_column' ] = true;
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Comment: many many thanks!  I will put this to the test on my development server today and get back with you!